# postgres: how to select a json column as text

Tags: postgresql

I have a json column, I want to select it as text, like :

```
select json_to_string(my_json_col) from my_table
```

How is that done ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would try:

```
SELECT CAST(my_json_col AS VARCHAR) FROM my_table
```

or

```
SELECT my_json_cal::varchar FROM my_table
```

(I haven't worked with JSON in PostgreSQL yet, but the above is how PostgreSQL handles type conversions)